# Where I can find infomation about ALL diseases of human beings?

Tags: disease

Is there any book or website about ALL diseases were officially registered ever?

I doubt that there is some book that has information about all diseases. I think that one book can hold only some diseases for instance A, B, C, D and another one C, D, E, F and it can always miss some of diseases.

In order not to read all books I just want to know is there any main source in internet which most doctors use?

I need this for filtering and finding disease according its symptoms.

**P.S.** I have not medical education, I am just curious about it, and I want always be sure that doctors not making mistake when diagnosing.

Comment: The problem is "ALL diseases" encompasses thousands of things, from the common cold to genetic diseases, mental diseases, etc. No single source will cover all that, so if that's what you mean, your question is far too broad. Or did you mean only infectious diseases? If so, that can be answered.

Comment: @CareyGregory I meant all of them. But if there is no single source of all diseases, even categorized ones are also welcomed. e.g. All genetic diseases, mental diseases etc.

Comment: " I want always be sure that doctors not making mistake when diagnosing." - You could go get enough education to be Gregory House and still not be sure of that. And consulting "Dr. Google" about symptoms can convince you that you should have been dead 3 weeks ago. I applaud the interest, but I would trust in the people that have obtained the degrees and certifications.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any book or website about ALL diseases were officially registered ever?

The best you're going to get is the International Classification of Disease (ICD) which is developed by the World Health Organisation. It's currently at version 10. The draft version of ICD-11 can be found [here](https://icd.who.int/dev11/l-m/en).

In case you're unable to find it, just note that it does not list *drapetomania*, or the mental illness that compels black slaves to flee their masters. That went out of vogue mid-1800s.

So, the ICD falls short for your requirements: it only lists all *currently* recognised diseases, not *ever*.

> In order not to read all books I just want to know is there any main source in internet which most doctors use?

Okay, what you're asking for is entirely different than a list of all registered diseases.

The standard reference is something like [UpToDate](https://www.uptodate.com), but it's a paid subscription. Another common one is [Best Practice](http://bestpractice.bmj.com/info/). That one has a free trial.

> I need this for filtering and finding disease according its symptoms.

Unfortunately, if diagnosis were as simple as that, then a computer would do it.

Comment: And another +1 for " if diagnosis were as simple as that, then a computer would do it"  The OP is talking about the differential diagnosis process basically, and there are programs like Diagnosaurus and Isobel and VisualDx that can generate a wide list of differential diagnoses based on some signs and symptoms - but that list is not very useful unless you have the training to work through the differential and determine what is likely/unlikely and concerning/reassuring.  The list is more likely to frighten than be useful to the average person.